# How to Clear all previous activities~?

Tags: android, android-activity

Activity Flow in my app.

> WelcomeActivity -> SignInActivity -> SignUpActivity ->
>   TabsActivity(this is main) -> ...

---

[image: Activity Stack]

---

I want to close all previous activities (Welcome, SignIn, SignUp) when start TabsActivity.

I try several method...

1. TabsActivity. clear task on launch=true  ? but not work (maybe)
2. TabsActivity. launch mode = singleTask ? but not work

But I do not want to "save 3 activities and call each activity.finish()"

Depending on the situation, "available 2 or 4 activities not 3", or
"I do not know What activities is in activity stack".

---

I want to clear all previous activities, regadless of any situation.

Help me :)

Sorry my poor english... Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you might want to try starting your `TabsActivity` with the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` clears the history.

Answer (score 0):

**Clear Backstack** of android, from where you are calling tabActivity

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClassToLaunch.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will finish the previous activities

Answer (score 0):

To Close Previous Activities ,you should start New Activity with startActivityForResult and then before finishing the current Activity with finish() call , setResult(value) for previous Activity ,the previous Activity will then get a callback where you can call finish() for the previous Activity.